# Implement Tiles 3 with a Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying to implement Apache Tiles 3 in my Spring MVC application, so I have added the following dependency to the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

as far as I've understood from Tiles website this should be enough to add everything including JSP support (please correct me if I am wrong).

Now my problem is that I don't understand how (where) to add the following bean info? Shall it be added to servlet-context.xml? I will appreciate it so much if someone can guide me please on where this info should be added

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"></property>
<property name="order" value="0"></property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"
id="tilesConfigurer">
<property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"></property>
</bean>
```

Note my application using Spring MVC, Maven and Hibernate.

Thanks for your time

pom.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mydomainname</groupId>
  <artifactId>crm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Inventory</name>
  <properties>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.15</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
      <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target</directory>
    <finalName>crm-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>E:\springsource\workspace\Inventory\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Here is full stack of error shown:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userService' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1672)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

and finally here are the errors I am getting:

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver' not found
    - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver' not found [config set: 
     Inventory/web-context]

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer' not found
    - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer' not found [config set: 
     Inventory/web-context]
```

root-context.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <import resource="security-context.xml"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomainname.crm" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="123456789" />
     </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize"><value>100000</value> </property>    
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tiles 3 is not working with Spring, at least up to version 3.1.0. Tiles version 2.2 works smoothly with Spring up to version 3.1.0.

All I had to do was to add bean info in servlet-context.xml, add dependency, build the tiles.xml, templates and that's it. Everything is simply working smoothly.

Comment: That's correct.

Spring-3.2 comes with support for Tiles-3.

Although that support is compatible with spring-3.0 and spring-3.1
 just download and add to your classpath http://wever.org/spring-webmvc-tiles3-3.2.0.RC2-finn-1.jar

Comment: Hava look at this post. I have a step by step list how to create an example with Spring 3.2 and Tiles 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924653/how-to-remove-a-tile-in-apache-tiles-for-a-specific-view

Comment: You can even integrate Tile3 with Spring 4.1.5 have a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-tiles

Answer (score 1):

`ViewResolver` is a component type used by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Add your `TilesViewResolver` and related beans to your servlet context configuration.

Comment: I've tried adding TilesViewResolver and TilesConfigurer beans to servlet-context.xml but I am always getting an error: Multiple annotations found at this line: - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver' not found - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver' not found [config set: Inven/web-context]. I tried refreshing, cleaning but nothing works :( Any thoughts how I can resolve this?

Comment: @MChan Do you have the tiles libraries on your classpath?

Comment: I've added Tiles dependency in pom.xml and all Tiles jars are downloaded and in place

Comment: @MChan Delete your local repo in `.m2` and try again.

Comment: Same results after deleting .m2

Comment: @Mchan Please post your pom.xml and the full stack trace.

Comment: I've just posted pom.xml, full stack and error I see as an Edit to my original question...thanks

Comment: Any luck with the stack? did it revel anything for you?

Comment: @Mchan Other than the not founds, you seem to be missing a `userService` bean. Have you declared one?

Comment: may I ask what do you mean by not founds I didn't change any file location or settings all I did was delete the .m2 folder! May you please suggest what I should check to solve the not found problem. I didn't come near userservice bean or anything as I said everything was cool for months until I thought of adding tiles and removing .m2 folder

Comment: @MChan The exception you posted `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userService' is defined` states that there is no `userService` bean defined. Do you define it anywhere. Try updating your question again with your context configuration.

Comment: Ok will do once I am back to my pc. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've updated the question with the root-context.xml file content