# Add tiles templates to Spring WEB MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I am beginner in Spring MVC. I want to add tiles template on my project, when I try to add Servlet-Context on my MVC web Project I faced with next error.

Can any one help me with where is the error. I spend a lot hours to fix this error, but I Can't.

When I add next code on servet context:

```
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
<beans:property name="definitions">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:list>
</beans:property>
```

I Get next alert:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer' not found [config set: easymangercrweb/web-context] servlet-context.xml /easymangercrweb/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet  line 26 Spring Beans Problem

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389981/implement-tiles-3-with-a-spring-mvc-application